# Getting npm 401 Auth issue when deploying Sveltekit site to Vercel

Tags: npm, vercel, sveltekit

When trying to deploy my Sveltekit site to Vercel, I'm getting npm authentication issue. The same was working fine initially when web app was created and pushed to repo.

> npm create svelte@latest my-app

After adding some dependencies (DaisyUI and Tailwind css) and doing npm install, it started to give the deployment error.

[image]

Here is the project`s package.json

```
{
    "name": "reactive-tut-site",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "svelte": "^3.54.0",
        "svelte-check": "^3.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^5.0.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "daisyui": "^2.51.6"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

Svelte config file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    vite: {
        optimizeDeps: {
          entries: []
        }
      },
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing package-lock.json worked for me, the site got deployed after that.
The reason is package-lock.json stores the package resolution registry and I had installed the same with my work machine which is configured for JFrog antifactory. The two solutions were:

1. Update .npmrc to point to npmjs registry.
2. Remove package-lock.json.
   Second option seemed better fit and worked for me.
   Screenshot of package-lock.json
   [image]